# Attempting to debug hex instruction, but python clears my console?

Tags: python, binary, hex, driver

I'm writing a driver and am concatenating some hex instructions based on a few conditionals. Up until this point, all instructions have worked as intended.

A new instruction I was working on isn't working as intended, so I attempted to print out the instruction after concatenation and before execution to see what was wrong.

```
msg = '\xc2%s%s' % ('\x1b\x63', '07')
assert self.dev.ctrl_transfer(0x21, 9, 0x0300, 0, msg) == len(msg)
print(msg)
```

When I print it after concatenation it clears the console and prints '07' and then continues the rest of the driver execution. I'm able to print and execute every other instruction I've concatenated, such as the following, without issue.

```
msg = '\xc2%s%s' % ('\x1b\x72, '07')
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? Does the '\x63' byte tell python to do something I'm unaware of? It should just be concatenated to the rest of the instruction, followed by the '\x07' byte. Note, that if I include the '\x' before the '07' (unlike my code above) it still does the same thing, it just doesn't print '07', it leaves a blank line.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't paste screenshots of code/exceptions/interpreter sessions/etc., paste the actual text.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "hex instruction"? What kinds of instructions are these?

Comment: @abarnert They are binary instructions written in hex, being sent to a device connected to the terminal. Also, I'll update the post with text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character `'\x63'` is the same character as `'c'` (and a half-dozen other ways to spell it). The letter `c` doesn't mean anything special to Python.

The character `'\x1b'` right before the `c` is Escape. That doesn't mean anything special to Python either—but it probably does to your terminal. Most terminals use "escape sequences" that start with Escape and end with a letter to do things like scroll up, changing the main text color, or clear the screen.

If this is getting in the way of an interactive debugging session, you may want to consider printing the `repr` of the string rather than the string itself. The easiest way to do that is to not even use `print`:

```
>>> msg = b'\x1b\x63'
>>> msg
b'\x1bc'
>>> print(repr(msg))
b'\x1bc'
```

Notice that either way, it includes the `b` and the quotes—and that it hex-escapes all non-printable bytes. And it works basically the same with Unicode strings instead of byte string:

```
>>> msg = '\x1b\x63'
>>> msg
'\x1bc'
>>> print(repr(msg))
'\x1bc'
```

If you're using Python 2.x, you'll have `u` prefixes instead of none on the Unicode ones, and no prefixes instead of `b` on the bytes, but basically the same.

Comment: I'm aware of what the characters are; these are required instructions via the device firmware specs. The '\x63', or 'c', indicates a specific function. Thus '\xc2\x1b' is the command-prefix for the device, and the 'x07' meant to follow is a specific case under which to execute that command on the device. 

It's not executing the command for the case that '07' is supposed to specify, hence why I tried to print it. I tried what you said, printing the repr of the msg in my OP, and it printed 'A\x1bc\x07'. This would appear to be the correct instruction, I'm not sure where to go from here?

Comment: @shplaz The problem you described in your question is "When I print it after concatenation it clears the console and prints '07' and then continues the rest of the driver execution… It should just be concatenated to the rest of the instruction." But it sounds like that's exactly what's happening. When you had `'07'`, the string you built was `'A\x1bc07'`. If you print that, your console displays an A, clears the screen, then prints `07`. You changed it to `\x07`. When you print that, your console displays an A, clears the screen, and plays a bell (or does nothing).

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I was trying to print out my instructions to debug them, and was asking why this particular instruction acted differently upon printing, as that was preventing me from learning anything useful to debug. Your explanation makes perfect sense! My initial question title was misleading, as I was thinking of asking for debug help despite that being a separate issue.